# Реализовать разные действия при нажатии на ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую этот [плагин](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)
Мой код

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="oem"]').autoComplete({
        minChars: 4,

        source: function(term, response) {
            term = term.toLowerCase();
            $.getJSON('/search.json?oem='+ term, function (data) {
                var matches = [];
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    if (~data[i][0].toLowerCase().indexOf(term)) matches.push(data[i]);
                response(matches.slice(0,500));
            });
        },
        // отображение
        renderItem: function (item, search){
            search = search.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
            var re = new RegExp("(" + search.split(' ').join('|') + ")", "gi");
            return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-slug="' + item[4] + '" data-category="' + item[3] + '">' + '<font color="bbbbbb" style="font-style: italic">' + 'Категория, ' + '</font>'+ item[3].replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div><div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-detail="' + item[0] + '" data-make="' + item[1] + '" data-oem="' + item[1] + '">' + item[0].replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
        },
        // действия при клике 
        onSelect: function(e, term, item){
            // alert('Item "'+item.data('langname')+' ('+item.data('lang')+')" selected by '+(e.type == 'keydown' ? 'pressing enter' : 'mouse click')+'.'); // для примера 
            document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html"
            document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/products/" + item.data('make') + "/" + item.data('oem') + ".html"
        }
    });
});
```

Ссылки отображаются таким образом:

```
return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-slug="' + item[4] + '" data-category="' + item[3] + '">' + '<font color="bbbbbb" style="font-style: italic">' + 'Категория, ' + '</font>'+ item[3].replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div><div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-detail="' + item[0] + '" data-make="' + item[1] + '" data-oem="' + item[1] + '">' + item[0].replace(re, "<b>$1</b>") + '</div>';
```

В браузере это выпадающий список такого вида:

```
Категория
Название
Категория
Название
Категория
Название
```

ссылки я формирую так:

```
document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html"
document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/products/" + item.data('make') + "/" + item.data('oem') + ".html
```

нужно чтобы при нажатии на "Категория" срабатывало

```
document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html"
```

А при нажатии на "Название" срабатывало

```
document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/products/" + item.data('make') + "/" + item.data('oem') + ".html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", ".autocomplete-suggestion", function(e) {
  if ($(this).data("slug") != "") {
    document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html";
  } else {
    document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/products/" + item.data('make') + "/" + item.data('oem') + ".html;
  }
});
```

*Update*

```
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){
      if (item.data("slug") != "") {
        document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html";
      } else {
        document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/products/" + item.data('make') + "/" + item.data('oem') + ".html";
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a:contains('Категория')").click(function(){
    document.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/catalogs/" + item.data('slug') + ".html";
    return false;
});
```